# Is there any way to make a PDF with a form and text entry fields directly from a Google slides presentation?

Tags: pdf, google

My client wants me to create a pdf with editable fields from a Google Slides presentation slide. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google slides can be downloaded as PDF. They can be edited in Acrobat. Curves can be edited in Illustrator, if that's needed. Texts in slides are not curved, they are still text in PDFs. In Acrobat you can insert fields which can be filled in Adobe Reader and also can launch programmed code or open web pages or applications.

Even Adobe Reader can add texts and simple drawings to a PDF. Those additions are quite free format ones because they are actually for comments. It's not at all sure that other PDF readers show properly additions which are inserted in Adobe Reader with comment tools.

There's also other programs which claim to be ultimate PDF editors. They generally cost substantially less than Acrobat, but run a trial before you buy. People pay the price of Acrobat if they need its print production support or other functionality which is missing or implemented badly in low cost software. I have seen that some PDF editors create PDFs which are shown badly in Adobe Reader altough they seem to be perfect in other readers. I do not know who actually makes the the seen errors, but Adobe Reader is very widely used.